# Prevent new events be triggered on an element until currently event function finishes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider following:

```
$('#theElement').on('click',function(){

  $(this).animate(...);
  $(this).doThis(...);
  $(this).doThat(...);

  $('anotherElement').animate(...);
  $('anotherElement').doThis(...);
  $('anotherElement').doThat(...);

});
```

As you see, here is a simple delegate function for onClick event. Now how is possible to make during this function execution, no other event be triggered on "#theElement"?

I tried to use preventDefualt(), but it stops whole execution which means that animate(), doThis() etc will not run too.

Comment: preventDefault() shouldn't stop functions inside handler to be called

Comment: Set a Boolean flag (`$(this).data('flagname')`) when the function starts. Test for the flag in your other events. Clear the flag when your animations are complete.

Comment: @A. Wolff: nope, it just a typo in the question.

Comment: $(this).animate({
   
   //your stuff
  }, 5000, function() {
   // Animation complete.
    $(this).doThis(...);
  });

Comment: "I tried to use preventDefualt(), but it stops whole execution which means that animate(), doThis() etc will not run too" I'm refering to that, i mean even you use preventDefault() inside handler, functions 'still' inside handler should still be called

Comment: @A. Wolff not necessarily, check this fiddle and uncommet preventDefault() http://jsfiddle.net/p2NjH/

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'preventDefault'"   preventDefault() is method bound to event, not jquery object: http://jsfiddle.net/p2NjH/1/  If you are throwing error and not handle it, then ya js execution stop

Comment: @A. Wolff, thanks I did not know that before. Anyway I tried in my code but how can I "re-attach" it?

Comment: Use Blazemonger's answer or you will have to deal with `$._data(node,"events")` which could give you some headhaches http://jsfiddle.net/fgYyv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a Boolean flag on the element when the function starts.

```
$('#theElement').on('click',function(){
    $(this).data('flagname',true);
    // ...
```

Test for the flag in your other events.

```
if (!$(this).data('flagname')) {  // !(undefined) is true
   // run code
}
```

Clear the flag when your animations are complete.

```
var $this = $(this); // 'this' is locally scoped
$this.animate(/* ... */, function() { 
    $this.data('flagname',false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to nest them like this:

```
$(".yourclass").animate({}, time, function(){
   $(".yoursecondclass").animate({}, time, function(){
   });
});
```

Comment: Assume that there is no animate() and just doThis() and doThat(). Now what?